# is omp_set_num_threads thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, signals, openmp

I am considering to implement a mechanism to change the maximum number of OpenMP threads that my program uses at runtime. My idea is to have a signal handler that catches `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`, respectively to increase and decrease the number of threads. Since the signal can be caught at any time by any thread, can I call `omp_set_num_threads()` in the signal handler safely?

Comment: You can only run this outside a parallel block.

Comment: @Mehrdad so you suggest that I have the signal handler put the new value somewhere in a global, and apply that when I know it's safe to do so?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think that may be the only way -- I think you can only call it when the application is in single-threaded mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the *nthreads-var* ICV in each data environment is copied from its parent environment. Changes to *nthreads-var* made from inside a parallel region, e.g. by calling `omp_set_num_threads()`, affect only nested parallel regions started by the thread that made the `omp_set_num_threads()` call.

Examine the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (void)
{
  omp_set_num_threads(4);
  omp_set_nested(1);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      printf("First region, nthreads-var = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
      omp_set_num_threads(2);
    }
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
      #pragma omp single
      printf("Nested region, nthreads-var = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
    }
  }
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp single
    printf("Second region, nthreads-var = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
  }
  omp_set_num_threads(2);
  #pragma omp parallel
  {
    #pragma omp single
    printf("Third region, nthreads-var = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Its output is as follows:

```
First region, nthreads-var = 4
Nested region, nthreads-var = 2  <--- (1)
Nested region, nthreads-var = 4
Nested region, nthreads-var = 4
Nested region, nthreads-var = 4
Second region, nthreads-var = 4  <--- (2)
Third region, nthreads-var = 2   <--- (3)
```

Notable points:

1. Only the nested region that was spawned by the thread that called `omp_set_num_threads(2)` has its *nthreads-var* ICV set to 2. All other nested regions still inherit the original value of 4.
2. The call to `omp_set_num_threads()` does not affect subsequent parallel regions at the same level of nesting.
3. Only calls to `omp_set_num_threads()` from the serial part of the program affect subsequent top-level parallel regions.

Not shown here is the fact that once a parallel region is created, the number of threads in its team cannot be changed.

Therefore run-time control of number of OpenMP threads is possible if the program periodically spawns new parallel regions, e.g. in a big loop. In that case, it is possible to catch the signal and to manipulate a global variable with the value of the desired number of threads:

```c
volatile int g_num_threads;

void sighandler(int signum)
{
  switch (signum)
  {
    case SIGUSR1:
      g_num_threads++;
      break;
    case SIGUSR2:
      g_num_threads--;
      break;
  }
}

// The following loop is NOT part of a parallel region
while (some_condition)
{
   omp_set_num_threads(g_num_threads);
   #pragma omp parallel
   {
      // Do some work
   }
}
```

Alternatively, the `num_threads` clause could be used to set the number of threads to `g_num_threads`.